# How to return a failed promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback, promise

How would I return a promise but invoke its failure block immediately? Here's a gnarly way to do it:

```
if (fail) {
    var q = $q.deferred();

    $timeout(function() {
        q.reject("")
    }, 1);

    return q.promise;
} else {
  return $http.get("/").then(function(data) {});
}
```

Comment: why do you want to do that? please post all block of code

Comment: because I want to invoke the catch block in the caller function.

Comment: This seems fine. What is the problem you are facing. How are you catching the failure?

Comment: so what is `fail` where you get this value from other promise?, please post more info

Comment: you want to invoke the `catch` block in the caller function? then just throw an exception and don't return anything, like `throw new Error('Custom Message');`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
if( fail ) {
    return $q.reject(yourReasonObject);
}
else ...
```

Ref [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.%24q) :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function setLike(productId){
    return new Promise(function(succeed, fail) {
        if(!productId) throw new Error();
        jQuery.ajax({
            success: function (res) {
                succeed(res)
            }
        })
    })
}


    setLike(id).then(function(){

       //render

    }).catch(function(e){})
```